# How to change WHERE clause with conditional?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
select t1.a,
       t1.b,
       t2.c,
       ....
  from table1 t1,
       table2 t2,
       ...
 where ...
   and condition1
   and condition2
   and
  case
     when (t1.a in ('aa', 'bb') and
          t1.e = t2.e) then
      true
     when (t1.a in ('cc', 'dd') and
          t1.e = t2.f) then
      true
     else
      false
   end;
```

I want to determine where clause using a column value. Query above returns `ORA-00920 invalid relational operator` on last line. I checked [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) to adjust my clause. If `t1.a` is `aa` or `bb`, I must only select row if `t1.e = t2.e` return true. Now if `t1.a` is `cc` or `dd`, then it must only select row if `t1.e = t2.f`, comparing a different column. Is it possible to do that without procedures?

Comment: You can't use a CASE expression like that in a WHERE clause like that.  You should be able to re-write it with just AND/OR

Comment: CASE expressions are valid in a WHERE clause. It's the BOOLEAN constants (TRUE and FALSE) which aren't supported by the Oracle database engine. (I suppose this seemed like a Good Idea to someone Back In The Day. I won't presume to understand Why...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to fix the error, change true to 1 and false to 0 then equate it to 1. Case statement is like a function and expects an expression (like = 1).

```
and
  (case
     when (t1.a in ('aa', 'bb') and
          t1.e = t2.e) then
      1
     when (t1.a in ('cc', 'dd') and
          t1.e = t2.f) then
      1
     else
      0
   end) = 1;
```

Answer (score 7):

Why `case` at all? You produce trivial boolean outputs, they can be used directly.

```
where
   ...
   and ((t1.a in ('aa', 'bb') and t1.e = t2.e) or
        (t1.a in ('cc', 'dd') and t1.e = t2.f)
   )
```

Comment: I was asked to optimize this query since it will be run lots of times. I don't have any experience on Oracle Database, only on Java. Is this considered a good pratice? Nested booleans?

Comment: Nested Booleans are fine. Nearly any scalar expression in your `where` clause is fine. Things that need consideration are joins (`table1.x = table2.y`, etc), `group by`, and sub-selects; also look for `distinct`. In any optimization effort, `explain plan` is your best friend.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to write this is with proper `join` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause:

```
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on (t1.a in ('aa', 'bb') and t1.e = t2.e) or
        (t1.a in ('cc', 'dd') and t1.e = t2.f)
```

Or, because Oracle supports tuples:

```
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on (t1.a, t1.e) in ( ('aa', t2.e), ('bb', t2.e), ('cc', t2.f), ('dd', t2.f) )
```

Comment: While I'm not sure I'd say never, I do agree it's a best practice to use the ANSI join syntax, as it is clearer about inner-outer as well as separating access or join criteria (unlikely to change) from filtering criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean values are not supported by the Oracle database. They *are* available in PL/SQL, but the database product itself lacks Booleans, and thus you can't use values such as TRUE and FALSE in a query. Because of this, it's common to use the string values 'Y' and 'N' or 't' and 'f' to represent Boolean outcomes. I suggest rewriting your query as:

```
select t1.a,
       t1.b,
       t2.c,
       ....
  from table1 t1,
       table2 t2,
       ...
 where ...
   and condition1
   and condition2
   and case
         when (t1.a in ('aa', 'bb') and
              t1.e = t2.e)
           then 'Y'
         when (t1.a in ('cc', 'dd') and
              t1.e = t2.f)
           then 'Y'
         else 'N'
       end = 'Y'
```

Best of luck.